# How to solve this equation $x^5 +4^y=2013^z$ in positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

I think to solve the equation in positive integers. It appears in a contest and I don't remember where.

I obtain that $x$ must be an odd number and further $x=1 \, mod\, 4$.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If $x \equiv 1 \!\!\mod 4$, then  $x^5 \equiv 1 \!\!\mod 4$. I think this is a hint to consider the entire equation $\!\!\mod 4$.

Comment: It might help to notice that $2013\equiv0\bmod{11}$ and $x^5\equiv\pm1\bmod{11}$.

Comment: Using Gerry Myerson's hint and checking $\mod 11$, we see that $y=5k, k\in\mathbb N$. Also, checking $\mod 4$, we see that $x$ is odd. Checking $\mod 3$, we see that $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$.

Comment: If $5\mid x$, then (checking $\mod 25$ and knowing that $y=5k$) $10\mid z$, contradiction (Fermat's Last Theorem). Thus $5\not\mid x$.

Comment: Checking $\mod 8$, if $y\ge 2$, then $z=2m, m\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: [spoilers](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3119988)